# Magento: Getting a session value in a CMS page?

Tags: redirect, magento-1.4

I have a controller that redirects to a static CMS page. In that page I want to display a string, but only if the redirect from the controller took place. So my plan was to set a session value in the controller and display that in the CMS page. How can that be done?

Is there another approach to that problem? This is how I make the redirect in the controller:

```
$this->_redirect('advice/something');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a block for your module which just echos out the session variable, and then use

```
{{block type="yourmodule/blockname" name="sessionvariable"}}
```

In the content of your CMS page. That's all I can come up with off the top of my head!